# hashtable implementation in C?

Tags: c, hashtable

I was wondering if you knew of a robust implementation of a hashtable in C. I'm looking for something other than ghashtable in glib.
Thanks.

Comment: I was about to suggest glib. Perhaps you could state why that's not suitable for you, so we can understand your constraints better.

Comment: yes, i guess you're right and i should stop fooling around. I wanted to look into my options, that's all.

Comment: I would prefer an alternative to Glib because it is GPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard good things about the [GLib Hash Table](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html).

Answer (score 2):

A simple one in libc, see <hsearch.h> and `man hsearch`.

Update: just found that you can implement hashtable very easily with the help of `hlist` from Linux kernel. Take a look at <list.h> in Linux kernel source code for `hlist_head/node` and their operations.

Answer (score 2):

In C:

- As previously mentioned `g_hash_table` in gLib:
  http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html
- `uthash`: https://github.com/troydhanson/uthash
- `khash` in klib: https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib
- `cdada_map` in libcdada: https://github.com/msune/libcdada (C API, backend C++)

If you can/want to use C++:

- `std::map` in libstdc++ (look into `std::unordered_map` too)
- As noted before (updated link) `sparsehash`: https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash (look into dense too)

Answer (score 1):

Will [this hashtable](http://www.pleyades.net/david/hashit.php) work? (got the link from the second post of [this thread](http://www.unix.com/programming/33629-hash-table-implementations-c-language.html))

Perhaps [this one](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/) will?

(got the above from a Google search for "hashtable in c", am not a C programmer)

Answer (score 1):

For a hash table I'd use [google-sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/)

PD: I don't know your requirements, but take a look at [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/), bear in mind it exists just in case.

**update**

[Memory Structures Library (MemSL2),](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memsl2/) o [MemSL2 in another link](http://www.memorystructures.com/)
it has implementations (one in pure C and wrappers for C++) of structures, for example, AVL trees, threaded trees, ..., and

- Hash Tables with Separate Chaining,
- Hash Tables with User-Defined Paging
- Hash Tables with Dynamic Paging

Comment: that was nice (google-sparsehash), but I'm after a pure C implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using the Apache Portable Runtime? It's license is very liberal and it provides a decent hashtable implementation:

http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group__apr__hash.html